# Getting Error: ImportError: No module named 'cv2' in Geany python editor

Tags: python, opencv

I'd finally installed OpenCV 4.1.0-dev in my raspberry pi with success,

I checked that in Terminal by :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.1.0-dev'
```

But then when I try to execute a python script inside Geany, the code doesn't get executed and I get an error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "car_detection.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

1- First, I tried `sudo reboot` and rebooted my raspi, it doesn't change anything.

2- I even searched for the settings to change the python interpreter in Geany.. but nothing, because Geany is a text editor. the only thing that I can make is to change (python)--> to (python3) because I was compiling and working with Python 3.

3- The last thing that I did is to delete my project and re-create a new one, but even this step I guess didn't make sense.

I wish anyone could help for giving a solution to this problem, 
Personally, for now, I'm working temporarily in Python3 (IDLE), it helps me, so I can execute my codes there and edit them perfectly. even those for OpenCV.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30378105/1151724